# text value assign when image is selected android

Tags: android, imageview

[image]

i want to set text value as image id on onItemSelected()

1> i have main activity 
2> image gallery adapter

when i select image in log i can show the image id but how to set value from image gallery adapter class to main activity xml file

Comment: What do you want to acheive be specific

Comment: use that link http://moorandroid.blogspot.in/p/gallery-view.html

Comment: when particular image is selected set value to text view but xml layout set to main activity and image gallery adapter dont have xml file so from adapter i want to set the value to text view which is present in main activity

Comment: anand see this i send u the code

Comment: What should i do tell me any one pleas